# AutocompleteService.getPlacePredictions returns ZERO_RESULTS with apartment number

Tags: google-maps-api-3

When calling [AutocompleteService.getPlacePredictions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-autocomplete-service#AutocompleteService.getPlacePredictions) with the following `request` parameter's `input` field set to an address like `3395 Michelson Dr, Irvine, CA 92612`, I get a matching result back as expected.

However, a status of `ZERO_RESULTS` is returned if the address includes an apartment number, as with any of the following examples:

```
3395 Michelson Dr APT 1306
3395 Michelson Dr, APT 1306
3395 Michelson Dr APT 1306, Irvine, CA 92612
3395 Michelson Dr, APT 1306, Irvine, CA 92612
3395 Michelson Dr, Irvine, CA 92612 APT 1306
3395 Michelson Dr, Irvine, CA 92612, APT 1306
3395 Michelson Dr #1306
3395 Michelson Dr, #1306
3395 Michelson Dr #1306, Irvine, CA 92612
3395 Michelson Dr, #1306, Irvine, CA 92612
3395 Michelson Dr, Irvine, CA 92612 #1306
3395 Michelson Dr, Irvine, CA 92612, #1306
```

Is this the intended outcome? If so, is there a correct way to get similar place predictions while allowing for an apartment or suite number to be included with the input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been answered in a support issue (https://issuetracker.google.com/35830389#comment3) :

> Support for subpremise elements (apt. / suite) is limited. Place
>   Autocomplete is not intended to support these universally.
>
> Geocoding API will find these places, and return subpremise elements
>   in address_components:
>
> 9500 Bryn Mawr Avenue #650: 
>   https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3D9500%2520Bryn%2520Mawr%2520Avenue%2520%2523650%2520Redlands%26nfw%3D1
>
> 1403/648 Bourke Street:
>   https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3D1403/648%2520Bourke%2520Street%26nfw%3D1
>
> 130 Bowdoin st., apt. 1010:
>   https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3D130%2520Bowdoin%2520st.%252C%2520apt.%25201010%26nfw%3D1
>
> Geocoding can be used as a fallback behind Autocomplete for these
>   queries, the Geocoder Tool at
>   https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/
>   does this to some extend: if you hit Enter without picking a
>   suggestion, your input is sent to the Geocoding service. This helps
>   with 1st and 3rd examples above.
>
> If you need to support suite/apt beyond that, there is a somewhat more
>   complex fallback option:
>   - use the placeIdOnly option of Autocomplete class to capture the suggestion's description (e.g. "1403/648 Bourke Street Melbrourne,
>   Victoria, Australia")
>   - match this description against a set of regular expressions to detect suite/apt in them, e.g. "\d+/\d+.*Australia" to detect 123/45
>   ... Australia)
>   - if there is a match, send the description to the Geocoding service, otherwise, request details for by Place ID This can still be
>   accomplished without coding your own Autocomplete widget.